# How to Calculate Kinect Joint Rotation from Translation XYZ?

Tags: c#, algorithm, rotation, kinect

I am using Kinect for Windows SDK and trying to generate A BVH File from capturing the skeleton and joint movements from the Kinect sensor. I just need to calculate the joint rotations from the `Joint.Position` (translation) data to be able to generate the file with motion data.

I have been searching for a while but I haven't found a guide on how to calculate it.

Comment: Perhaps a link or more clear description of what your trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

The new 1.5xxx Kinect SDK came out a few days ago, and has a Skeleton API that has helpers for this exact task. This would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You may try use Brekel Kinect software to record BVH files directly. It uses openNI.